# Change DC motor direction with rectified voltage

Tags: ac, dc-motor, bridge-rectifier, thyristor

I'm working with the following circuit:

[image]

It has a DC motor. The VDC can be changed by controlling the thyristor turn on angle.

I would like to add a switch to also change the DC motor direction, but I'm confused about how can it be done.

I've searched and found a H bridge, but would it work with this configuration? What changes should I keep in mind?

Comment: Use a DPDT switch and it should work. Do you know how to make a DPDT act as a reverser?

Comment: https://fdocuments.in/document/ac-igbt-drives-and-their-applications-dcs-nov-08.html

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a H bridge (4 switches)? If you just want to control rotary speed and direction, It is a fundamental "topology" to drive motors, it is current and voltage bidirectional, that means you can control speed, speed direction (voltage) and torque (current) and you can brake (negative current).

You can easily find any solution to that on any academic book. I'd recommend you take a look at this book: Electric Drives - Ion Boldea.

Good luck amigo.